# renaming .jpg files in a folder using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder that has bmp files , they may be 4 in a folder or 50 in a folder, but they are

```
image.bmp
image1.bmp
image2.bmp
```

I started a batch file with the below code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET counter=0
SET /P filename=Please enter the filename:
for %%G in (C:\Test_Folder) do (
  ren image*.bmp "%filename%""%counter%".bmp
  SET /A counter=%counter%+1;
  echo "%counter%"
)
pause
```

but the counter does not increment, can some one give some light to my code?

Comment: you have a [delayed expansion problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: how do I correct it?

Comment: it's described in my link.

Comment: `gci image*.bmp | rename -newname { $_ -replace "image", "picture " }`, in PowerShell. No need for batch files, it's $currentyear.

Comment: I corrected it , and the counter does move to the next number. But I cannot get the loop to work to rename the rest of the files :(

Comment: `ren image*.bmp "%filename%!counter!.bmp"` ? All of them to the same name, trying it [n] times? Won't work. Logical failure.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET counter=0
SET /P filename=Please enter the filename:
for %%G in (C:\Test_Folder\image*.bmp) do (
  ren "%%~G" "%filename%!counter!.bmp"
  SET /A counter+=1
  echo "!counter!"
)
pause
```

Changes:
using delayed expansion for the `counter` variable.
`for`processes matching files in the folder instead of the folder itself.
use `ren` to rename single files instead of wildcard usage.
`SET /A counter+=1` instead of `SET /A counter=!counter!+1` (does the same, but improved readabilty).